# is there an editor for csdef files?

Tags: azure

I am using Window Azure and I need to edit csdef files.

However, Visual studio 2010 opens these files as xml files.

Is there a tool to edit these files?

Or do I need to edit them by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio will map most of parameters onto the "settings" of the role node that is located in the .ccproj file. When you create a cloud service solution you get two projects, .ccproj is one of them, it contains "Roles" subfolder that contains a node called with the name of your role. When you right-click it and ask for properties you get a nice set of tabs containing most of (or maybe even all) properties that correspond to the contents of .csdef and .cscfg files.

Also those files actually contain XML, so editing them as XML is natural (but perhaps not very convenient).